# GaussianProcess regression results correct...up to a scale factor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am running GaussianProcess regressions over some very noisy data. When I scatter plot predictions (which are, I know, predictions of means) vs actuals, I get a beautiful only slightly noisy y=x line.

Only one problem: the slope is completely wrong. Is there any way I can address this without building a second-stage linear regressor?

I regret I cannot share my data, but my model is fairly basic. X is a matrix with 10 columns, y a matrix with 1 column. I am using 1,000 examples to train and plot.

*added*: The below plot is plotting predicted versus actual. Given that I am using a nonlinear kernel, I find it strange that the GP regressor can find a relationship which is accurate up to a multiplier (slope).

[image]

```
kernel = (
    GP.kernels.RationalQuadratic(
        length_scale=.8,
        length_scale_bounds=(1e-3,1e3),
        alpha=.8,
        alpha_bounds=(1e-3,1e3),
        )
    + GP.kernels.WhiteKernel()
    )

gp = Pipeline( [
    ('scale',preproc.StandardScaler()),
    ('gp',GP.GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)),
    ] )
gp.fit( X, y )
```

*added*: I'm a bit embarrassed, but I'm new to the GP world in particular and, really, regression as a ML problem in general. I had not plotted the model's performance over a test set, which revealed a strong overfit. Additionally, I've added an idiom to my code to deal with scikit-learn's default GP behavior, i.e., optimization makes me sad when I give it significant quantities of data, by "pretraining" on a small quantity of data, using the optimizer to find reasonable values for the kernel parameters, then "training" a much larger quantity of data. This allowed me to widen the parameter search and use multiple restarts on the optimizer, finding a much more generalizable model...which was almost all noise. Which was what I was expecting, really.

```
kernel = (
    GP.kernels.RationalQuadratic(
        length_scale=1,
        alpha=.5,
        )
    + GP.kernels.WhiteKernel(
        noise_level=1,
        )
    )*GP.kernels.ConstantKernel()

gp = Pipeline( [
    ('scale',preproc.StandardScaler()),
    ('gp',GP.GaussianProcessRegressor(
        kernel=kernel,
        n_restarts_optimizer=3,
        alpha=0,
        )),
    ] )
print("pretraining model for target %s..." % c)
x_pre = X_s.values[:500,:]
y_pre = y_s_scl[:500,:]
gp.fit( x_pre, y_pre )

gp = Pipeline( [
    ('scale',preproc.StandardScaler()),
    ('gp',GP.GaussianProcessRegressor(
        kernel=kernel,
        optimizer=None,
        alpha=0,
        )),
    ] )
print("training model for target %s..." % c)
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Have you tried centering your data before doing the regression? (subtracting the mean of all the output values from each output). I know the Gp Toolbox in Matlab doesn't need the data to be centered, but I am not sure about the GP in sklearn. See:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia

OLD COMMENT:
Your initial values for the hyperparameters in the kernel function (i.e. length-scale and alpha) are very important. During the fit(), the hyperparameters are optimized and local maximum of hyperpareters can be found, which could in turn affect your result. Depending on the bounds you set for these hyperparameters, many local maximum can be found depending on the initial conditions. 
On the sklearn site it says:
"As the LML may have multiple local optima, the optimizer can be started repeatedly by specifying n_restarts_optimizer."
You may try using the RBF function as it is a very traditional kernel function for the GP.

Comment: While your answer is extremely detailed and helpful, it would be better if you post an answer once you are clear with the question. Clarifications should be asked for via comments or chat.

Comment: With just starting out on here, it won't let me comment on the main question until 50 rep. points. I guess I could chat. Seems a little counter intuitive to prohibit comments to new members. I guess they have their reasons though.

Comment: Yeah it seemed absurd to me at first too. Then I realized it made sense when I saw the high number of low quality posts that throng this site from people who don't even know how to use Google, let alone StackOverflow. Here's 10 points to you, btw :)

Comment: Thank you Ray- very nice of you! Hopefully the first 50 will come quick enough so I can start doing real comments. I will probably see what Andreus says and then delete this answer and put up a new one if I can help at all.

Comment: (1) see edit. (2) I will play more, but I have tried much of this already, including RBF (exact same results, also RationalQuadratic is a superset of RBF). (3) I have not, but doubt it would work, because I am using a nonlinear RBF-like kernel to get this result. (4) I have 300,000 points. The results do not differ from training on 1,000 through 4,000 points and with 10 input dimensions the solver gets overloaded with much more data.

Comment: See my final edits above. I'm inclined to delete the question, but I know you're trying to build rep, ssh22.

Comment: I understand now- I find it odd that the GP was able to accurately predict the non-linear relations between your inputs space and the outputs, but that it is consistently off by a linear amount. That is really odd. So getting back to your main question, I don't know what would cause that exactly. You could try looking into a kernel with automatic relevance determination (ARD). The less complex kernels weight all of the input directions equally and hence there is only one hyperparameter for the length scale. A kernel with ARD will have a length-scale for each input dimension.

Comment: ARD might help find the most important dimensions (the best features)that then lead to the highest likelihood ratio. I wonder if having just one length scale is favoring one input dimension that doesn't contribute as much to the outputs as the others. Of course, ARD is computationally more expensive. I will keep thinking about it, but like you say if it is consistently off by a linear amount you could use that with a second linear correction. If you need to delete this question I am fine with that. Will it still let me keep the rep points from it?

Comment: Just edited about data centering, I don't know if you had tried that or not. I need to look into this, but in the Gp toolbox in Matlab there is a hyperparameter for signal variance. If there is a hyperparameter for this in sklearn, then that would also be very important to get the initial value to be reasonable with your collected data variance.